# Could not load oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver. java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ivr-scan.dc.dialog.lk:1521/ivrdb

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm having common error, but unable to figure it out how to get this sorted. I'm getting following exception and I have imported ojdbc14.jar file correctly. Also it is in tomcat lib directory but application cannot find the driver.

Exception:

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
at java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:463)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at gsmprepaid.DbCon.getMyIvrDataSource(DbCon.java:362)
at com.realsoftinc.dtl.services.DTLDatabaseManagerNoSession.getMyIvrDataSource(DTLDatabaseManagerNoSession.java:142)
at com.realsoftinc.dtl.services.DTLDatabaseManagerNoSession.getCMSMyIvrConnection(DTLDatabaseManagerNoSession.java:166)
at com.realsoftinc.dtl.services.MyIvr1DBThread.run(MyIvr1DBThread.java:138)

Unable to make connection with DB
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ivr-scan.dc.dialog.lk:1521/ivrdb
```

[image: Here I have attached the jar file that I have imported.]

Source Code:

```
Connection Con = null;
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ivr-scan.dc.dialog.lk:1521/ivrdb";
String dbUName = "IVRDTL";
String dbPswd = "ivrdtl";
String Driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

    public DbCon() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(this.Driver).newInstance();
}

public Connection getMyIvrDataSource() throws IOException {
    try {

        System.out.println("Trying to connect");
        this.Con = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.dbUName,
                this.dbPswd);
        System.out
                .println("Connection Established Successfull and the DATABASE NAME IS:"
                        + Con.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to make connection with DB");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Con;
}
```

Comment: Why are you loading a Java 1.4 JDBC driver with Java 7? Upgrade to a new JDBC driver.

Comment: Do i need to use ojdbc7.jar?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Depends on that too!

Comment: @dmaprasad Yes, `ojdbc7.jar`